# R script line numbers at error?

Tags: debugging, r

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445964/r-script-line-numbers-at-error) from a year ago, and I'm using `R version 2.11.1 (2010-05-31)`, but  still getting error messages without line numbers.

Any solution?

Comment: I get error messages with line numbers.  How are you loading your scripts?

Comment: @Shane I'm using Rscript. How are you loading your scripts?

Comment: I'm using source() from the windows GUI.

Comment: I'm not running Windows but Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers given there are still valid. Returning line numbers from a script ain't that straight-forward, but R can give you a lot more information on where the error can be found.

You could use the error options to save the info in a file, for example :

```
options(error = quote({
  sink(file="error.txt");
  dump.frames();
  print(attr(last.dump,"error.message"));
  traceback();
  sink();
  q()}))
```

The function findLineNum() could be used if you have the name of the file somewhere available. If you have the error message, you could do something like :

```
dump.frames()
x <- attr(last.dump,"error.message")
ll <- gsub("Error in (.*) : .*","\\1",x)
lln <- findLineNum(srcfile,ll)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, that's kind'a disappointing that it's not yet implemented by default in R. Seems to me like a very desirable feature.

Comment: This doesn't help if the error is at the top level of an R script.

Answer (score 0):

In the upcoming R 2.14, the core team is making progress toward implementing this feature. Functions in scripts loaded with `source(file=..., keep.file=TRUE)` will contain an attribute `srcref`, which identifies the range of characters corresponding to the function's definition in an in-memory copy of the source file stored as an object of class `srcfilecopy`.

This does not immediately provide line-level debugging, but it lets you get approximate line numbers if you're willing to get your hands dirty. Also, it's progress.