# R script line numbers at error 2016

Tags: r, debugging

On 2009, @forkandwait [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445964/r-script-line-numbers-at-error) and there was no straightforward answer.
One year later, @David B [asked it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650444/r-script-line-numbers-at-error) and the situation was no different.

So now, six years later, with R version 3, I'm asking this very basic question again:

**Is there any way to get error messages with line numbers in R?**

If there's still no straightforward way to do this, I want to know what strategies you use to debug your script.

Comment: The answers haven't really changed. There are lots of debugging tools in IDEs like RStudio, and general techniques are covered by the linked question.