# traceback() for interactive and non-interactive R sessions

Tags: r, traceback

I observed a different between an interactive and non-interaction R session about `traceback()` which I do not understand. For the code below, it will produce an error, but in an interactive R session, I can see the traceback information, whereas if I save the code to `test.R` and call it via `Rscript test.R` or `R -f test.R`, I can no longer see the traceback:

```
f = function() {
  on.exit(traceback())
  1 + 'a'
}
f()
```

In an interactive R session:

```
> f = function() {
+   on.exit(traceback())
+   1 + 'a'
+ }
> f()
Error in 1 + "a" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
1: f()
```

Non-interactive execution:

```
$ Rscript test.R 
Error in 1 + "a" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
Calls: f
No traceback available 
Execution halted
```

I did not see an explanation in `?traceback`, and I'm wondering if there is a way to enable traceback for non-interactive R sessions. Thanks!

Comment: `traceback` looks for an object called `.Traceback` in the `baseenv()`. It looks (from `src/main/errors.c`) like this is only created if, among other conditions, `R_Interactive || haveHandler`. Without `.Traceback`, you will get the message "No traceback available". There's also a warning under `?traceback` that mentions `.Traceback`.

Comment: If you just set options(error=traceback) in your script and remove your on.exit call, you will have the desired effect. Although it does create duplication because of the "step" of the error.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, As far as I can tell, that still won't give you access to traceback info, although the call stack gets returned anyway in the case of an error in a non-interactive session.

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Automatic-traceback-td845199.html

Comment: @BenBarnes Your comments are a useful Answer, care t add them as such?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With default values of its arguments, `traceback()` will look for an object named `.Traceback` in the `baseenv()` for information on the call stack. It looks (from `src/main/errors.c`) like `.Traceback` is only created if, among other conditions, `R_Interactive || haveHandler`, suggesting that this object is not created during non-interactive sessions. If there is no object named `.Traceback`, you will get the message "No traceback available".

However, by passing a non-NULL value to the `x` argument of `traceback()`, one can obtain information about the call stack from a non-interactive session. With a non-zero integer value (indicating the number of calls to skip in the stack), c-level functions (`R_GetTraceback`) are called to investigate the call stack instead of looking in `.Traceback`.

So there are a couple ways to obtain traceback information in a non-interactive session:

```
f = function() {
  on.exit(traceback(1))
  1 + 'a'
}
f()
```

Or, setting `options` as Brandon Bertelsen suggested

```
options(error=function()traceback(2))
```

The different values passed to `x` in the two examples account for the different number of functions to skip

1. In the `on.exit` example, `traceback(1)` skips the call to `traceback()`.
2. In the example setting `options`, there is an extra anonymous function that calls `traceback()` which should/could also be skipped.

In the example in the OP, there's not much more information gained by using `traceback()` compared to the automatic traceback provided in the case of an error in a non-interactive session. However, with functions that take (and are passed) arguments, using `traceback()` will be much more informative than the standard presentation of the call stack in the non-interactive session.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not realize that setting `x` to a number also works for non-interactive R sessions.

Comment: Note that using `options(error=function() traceback(2))` will cause scripts to exit successfully even when an error occurs! A solution is to use `error=function() { traceback(2); if(!interactive()) quit("no", status = 1, runLast = FALSE) }` instead (the stop arguments used here are from the [default error behaviour](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/stop.html)).

Comment: This is still somewhat problematic.  When using the  `options(error=function()traceback(2))` leads to anomalous output.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933667/r-executes-code-in-function-when-there-is-a-syntax-error-and-function-is-not-exp?noredirect=1#comment92778349_52933667

Answer (score 5):

There is also the possibility to dump debugging information and load them later on. (See good `?debugger` help pages and comments on the topic)

via e.g.:

```
options(error = quote(dump.frames("testdump", TRUE)))
```

...

```
load("testdump.rda")
debugger(testdump)
```

or

```
options(error = quote({dump.frames(to.file = TRUE); q(status = 1)}))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `options(error=function()traceback(2))` is that it does not stop the script execution, which is really really dangerous.

To avoid that you can use:

```
options(error = function() { 
  traceback(2)
  options(error = NULL)
  stop("exiting after script error") 
})
```

which will properly print the stack trace, then exit properly.

Comment: Does this approach produce an exit code that indicates that the program failed?

Comment: yes. since it exits via a stop()

Comment: Thanks. Digging into [the docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/stop.html) confirms: `The default behaviour (the NULL error-handler) in interactive use is to return to the top level prompt or the top level browser, and in non-interactive use to (effectively) call q("no", status = 1, runLast = FALSE).`

Answer (score 1):

[BenBarnes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13119318/2361465)'s answer and dshepherd's comment are life saving. I will add one more parameter to avoid clogging up the screen in case one of the parameters is very big.

```
options(error=function(){traceback(2,max.lines=3);if(!interactive())quit("no",status=1,runLast=FALSE)})
```