# Stopping R code execution upon error when run as non-interactive Rscript

Tags: r

How do I get an R (version 3.4.2, CentOS 6.9) script to stop on Error instead of happily continuing on?  My file :

```
$ cat tmp.R
a = 9
print(a)
print(b)
print(d)
print("Should never get here")
```

Running `tmp.R` non-interactively it:

```
$ Rscript tmp.R
Looking for libraries in : ~/.R/3.4.2-lib
[1] 9
Error in print(b) : object 'b' not found
Error in print(d) : object 'd' not found
[1] "Should never get here"
```

Question : How do I get R to stop execution upon encountering an error?

I've tried things like `options(error=stop)` and `options(error=browser)` which work in the interactive case but not non-interactive Rscript example.

Comment: With R 3.2.3 on ubuntu your script terminates as expected. Is a try-catch possible with a stop() in the catch block? Just checked with R 3.5.1: The script terminates as well after the error.

Comment: I don't a priori know where the error will occur and I don't want to use try-catch at every line of my code.  It just drives me nuts when an error occurs and causes cascading errors. The real error gets buried behind a bunch of useless output.

Comment: Also, I just tried with R 3.2.3 on CentOS 6.9 and I got the same output as above.  It would be silly if this type of behavior is system dependent.

Answer (score 1):

This is because I have set `options(error=traceback)` in my `.Rprofile`.  Commenting it out in my `.Rprofile` leads to code termination at line 3 as expected.  This raises issues with why this generates output.  See related questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933667/r-executes-code-in-function-when-there-is-a-syntax-error-and-function-is-not-exp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116099/traceback-for-interactive-and-non-interactive-r-sessions).