# R executes code in function when there is a syntax error and function is not explicitly called

Tags: r

This is interesting.  I'm on CentOS 6.9, R-3.4.2.  I have a code, `tmp.R`:

```
main<-function(){
    a = 9
    print(a) xyz
    print("Should never get here")
}
```

When I run this, `Rscript tmp.R`, I get

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"    a = 9
    print(a) xyz"
No traceback available
[1] "Should never get here"
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
No traceback available
```

This is pretty confusing because I never *actually* called `main()`.  In fact, if I remove the syntax error 
 (3rd line becomes `print(a)`), and I run it, there isn't any output.  This is the expected behavior in my mind.

**QUESTION** : Why does R execute code in a script when a syntax error occurs, even when the code isn't explicitly called(!)?

**EDIT** : It turns out that this behavior seems to be due to having `options(error=traceback)` being set in my `.Rprofile`.  This is undesirable behavior none the less.  It would still be desirable to be able to get tracebacks when in interactive mode and not do this strange code execution in non-interactive mode.

Comment: It isn't executing the code, it's *parsing* it in order to store it as an object in the calling environment. In this case, the parsing fails, not the execution of it. (This should be the case with `Rscript` or in the R console itself. Similarly, try `a <- list(x=1 y=2)` ... the object `a` is never created, because the creation of the contents of that object does not parse without error.)

Comment: Are you sure this is the output you get when you call Rscript (and not just `source()`-ing the file)? I do not get the same behavior (running R 3.4.4).

Comment: @r2evans but the line `[1] "Should never get here"` should only be printed during evaluation, not parsing. That "[1]" part is a big indicator that it's actually being evaluated, no?

Comment: @MrFlick : This is indeed the output of running `Rscript`. 

@r2evans : Is there a way to suppress this annoying output?  Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932440/stopping-r-code-execution-upon-error-when-run-as-non-interactive-rscript?noredirect=1#comment92775257_52932440

Comment: So, the it seems that the issue is with `options(error=traceback)` in `.Rprofile`.  When I comment it out, the script ends without executing the last print statement (as expected)

Comment: I see your point, good sleuthing.

Comment: Your `.Rprofile` can use `if (interactive()) {options(error=traceback)}` to conditionally change the error behavior during interactive and non-interactive sessions.