# Is there any way to see logs of a fatal error in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to write my own package that links with some C++ code.
I successfully managed to build and install the package and am now trying to run a function of the package.
When trying to do so i get a popup saying:

```
R Session Aborted
R encountered a fatal error.
The session was terminated.
```

Found a log anyone know how to resolve this?

```
22 Nov 2019 17:55:15 [rsession-mente] ERROR system error 10053 (De software op uw hostcomputer heeft een verbinding verbroken) [request-uri=/events/get_events]; OCCURRED AT: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:111; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) c:\jenkins\workspace\ide\windows-v1.2\src\cpp\session\http\SessionHttpConnectionImpl.hpp:116
```

Comment: Please give the names of your packages and a reproducible example.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116099/traceback-for-interactive-and-non-interactive-r-sessions

Comment: Like i mentioned before it's a self made package which links with C++ with RCPP. This is what errors:model <- credittree(formula = choice ~ .,
                data = train,
                control = credittree.control(minbucket = 3,
                                         minsplit = 10,
                                         maxdepth = 5,
                                         miniterations = 100,
                                         niterations = 500,
                                         ntrees = 100))

Comment: Are you using RStudio? https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554756-RStudio-Application-Logs

Comment: Yes i am, i managed to get a log and added it to the original post