# R: How to check how my R-Programm terminated?

Tags: r, error-handling

I have written some software in R that performs a job every night, triggered by a cron event.
Now I want the software to send out a notification based upon the exit status of the software.
There are thee possible states the software can be in after it finishes:

1. No Error occurred.
2. A error occurred, but it was caught by a `tryCatch`.
3. A error occurred and it was not caught, the software terminated unexpectedly.

For me the first two cases are summaries as "no error" and the last one as "error".

Then I have identified two different modes that change the way errorhandling in R works.

1. Whether we are in an [interactive R-Session or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116099/traceback-for-interactive-and-non-interactive-r-sessions).
2. Whether the `traceback(x)` value is set to `x=NULL` or an integer, in this example `x=1`.

To test the behavior of R in all these different scenarios I came up with a small MWE and a table to show my results.
You'll find the MWE below.
In this table you can see that there are several cases (e.g. Non-Interactive and `x=1`) where you have not enough information to discriminate the three different stages from one another.

How can I reliably determine from the `on.exit()`-Function how my R-Program terminated?
Or how can I reliably determine from the `on.exit()`-Function if my R-Program had an error?

| interactive | traceback(x) | test | No Error | uncaught Error | caught Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | 1 | nchar(geterrmessage())==0 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| TRUE | 1 | is.null(.traceback()) | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| TRUE | NULL | nchar(geterrmessage())==0 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| TRUE | NULL | is.null(.traceback()) | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| FALSE | 1 | nchar(geterrmessage())==0 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| FALSE | 1 | is.null(.traceback()) | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| FALSE | NULL | nchar(geterrmessage())==0 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| FALSE | NULL | is.null(.traceback()) | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |

```
test <- function(error, trace) {
  on.exit(
    {
      print(nchar(geterrmessage()) == 0)
      print(is.null(.traceback(trace)))
    },
    add = TRUE,
    after = TRUE
  )

  if (error == "c") {
    result <- tryCatch({
      "1" + 1
    }, warning = function(w) {
      print(w)
    }, error = function(e) {
      print(e)
    }, finally = {
      print("finally")
    })
  } else if (error == "u") {
    "1" + 1
  } else if (error == "n") {
    1 + 1
  } else {
    print("BAD")
  }
}

.rs.restartR()
options(error = NULL)
test(error = "n", trace=NULL)

.rs.restartR()
options(error = NULL)
test(error = "u", trace=NULL)

.rs.restartR()
options(error = NULL)
test(error = "c", trace=NULL)

#########

.rs.restartR()
options(error = NULL)
test(error = "n", trace=1)

.rs.restartR()
options(error = NULL)
test(error = "u", trace=1)

.rs.restartR()
options(error = NULL)
test(error = "c", trace=1)
```

Comment: There is no way for any language to report a total crash by  itself.  However, you should be able to craft a shell script or equivalent; have your R function create a dummy process and then let the shell script check the status of that process; if your function doesn't crash then have it terminate the dummy process on exit.

Comment: On the one hand you're completely right. On the other it is so close to working: When the traceback would work the same way in script-mode and interactively then I could do what I want. To me it still feels as a bug that traceback acts so differently in both modes.