# How to show error line number in R studio

Tags: r, syntax-error, rstudio

Is it possible to see the syntax error or runtime error line number (highlight also) generated after running the code in R studio?

I searched the options but couldn't find.

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445964/r-script-line-numbers-at-error because R language needs to support line numbers so that R Studio utilize it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, have a look at `?traceback`.

There are many ways to debug R code/script.  This is only one example.

In RStudio, from the `Debug` drop down menu option `On Error`, choose `Error Inspector` for (what I think is) the easiest debug mode for finding the line number of an error/bug.  You can also choose `Break in Code` to show the highlighted line of an R script that contains the error.

When the error occurs, you can click either of the small areas marked `Show Traceback` and `Rerun with Debug`.  The screen shot below shows the effect of clicking "Show Traceback" (hence it now says "Hide Traceback").   It tells me that the error occurred when R attempted to call `sample` (the third call).  `LENGTH` had not yet been defined.

[image]

Comment: i did check the Error Inspector and ran my code but i don't see any Hide Traceback or Rerun with Debug.

Comment: Version 0.98.501 – © 2009-2013 , i think it is the latest

Comment: @waheebyaqub Same here, I can get a stacktrace using `traceback()`, but no line numbers or any reference to a source file, regardless of selected options in the `Debug` menu. Debugging this way seems ridiculously painful. `Version 1.1.456 – © 2009-2018 RStudio, Inc.`

Comment: January 28, 2020 here now.  RStudio IDE still has no built-in line numbers for error messages.  This was requested in 2009 and here we are 11 years later, and it is still not built-in to the core of RStudio.  RStudio is a poor environment for debugging.