# rstudio's traceback() does not work interactively anymore

Tags: r, rstudio, traceback

I just started with debugging in rstudio. At the beginning everything worked as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222969/how-to-show-error-line-number-in-r-studio/23224183#23224183).

[image]

After I used `browser()`, I cannot get back to this status, that means there is no interactive field, where I can press the `hide traceback` or `return with debug` button. Does anybody know, what is going wrong?

- Suggestions above do not work.
- `traceback()` works but the message is not interactive anymore.
- `options(error = function(){.rs.breakOnError(TRUE)})` from here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202296047-error-recovery sets the value to TRUE, but still no interactive traceback appears.

RStudio Version

> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
>   arch     x86_64
>   os             mingw32
>   system         x86_64,
>   mingw32
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          2.2
>   year           2015
>   month          08
>   day            14
>   svn rev        69053
>   language       R
>   version.string R version
>   3.2.2 (2015-08-14) nickname       Fire Safety

Please let me know if you also need all `options()` settings.

**Edit November 2018**: Run a script with an error an interactive traceback active.

```
getOption("error")
(function () 
{
    .rs.recordTraceback(FALSE, 5, .rs.enqueueError)
})()
```

Destroy interactive traceback (No idea, what I did):

```
getOption("error")
(function () 
{
    .rs.recordTraceback(FALSE, 5, .rs.enqueueError)
})()
```

Thus, settings are the same and it unclear what happens...

Comment: Unfortunately, my suggestion didn't stick for me either, so I've deleted my answer. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same behavior. After programmatically setting the `error` option in R to `browser`, `traceback` or `recover`, the button in RStudio (Debug/On Error) didn't work anymore.

To resolve this I had to first reset the `error` option to it's default value `NULL`. After that I could get back the interactive debugger.

The following resets the option first to `NULL` and then sets the option to the behavior that you get with selecting (Debug/On Error/Error Inspector) in RStudio.

```
options(error = NULL)
options(error = function(){.rs.recordTraceback(TRUE)})
```

Comment: The following works for me:  
1. options(error = NULL)  
2. RStudio => Debug => On Error => Error Inspector  
However, it only works ONCE. Afterwards I have to do the same process again to make it work again.

The following does not work:  
1. options(error = NULL)  
2. options(error = function(){.rs.recordTraceback(TRUE)})

Comment: See discussion [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/218745527-No-traceback-or-R-code-information-when-error?page=1#community_comment_115000020928)

Comment: Link appears to be dead as of December 2019

Answer (score 1):

Running `options(error = traceback)` in console will output the traceback messages, but it will not work after restart RStudio. That is, you need to run `options(error = traceback)` every time launching RStudio.
[image]