# Return line number of a warning in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a place of the warning in the function:

```
fun <- function(x, y){
   z = sum(x,y)
   if(z > 15)
     warning("Potential problem")
   
   return(z)
}

x = 10; y = 20
fun(x, y)
```

The result I'd like to get is the line number of the warning (not only warning msgs created by developer) and the function name where it exists. The name of a function I can get with the `withCallingHandlers` function, however I don't know how to find the line number of the warning.

```
|function_name | warning_index | 
--------------------------------
|fun           |4              |
```

Comment: There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445964/how-to-get-r-script-line-numbers-at-error) about this asked in 2009. The simplest answer seems to be `options(show.error.locations = TRUE)` though it's from 2016 and some comments say it isn't reliable. Does it work for you?

Comment: It doesn't work. There is no change of the result. I'd like to get the line of a code where it spotted a warning, not an error so maybe because of that there is no effect for warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED to use base functions:

You can use `sys.calls()` to see the call stack, and then look through it for lines with debug info.  Here's a demonstration that does it.

```r
# First, some code that will generate a warning

fun <- function(x, y){
  z = sum(x,y)
  if(z > 15)
    warning("Potential problem")
  
  return(z)
}

x = 10; y = 20

# Here's a handler that looks through the call stack
# for locations.  Not all calls have recorded locations
# (most packages are installed without debug info) 
# but this will find the debug info if it is there,
# and add it to the warning message.

locatedWarnings <- function(e) {
  calls <- sys.calls()
  locations <- character()
  for (i in rev(seq_along(calls)))
    if (!is.null(srcref <- getSrcref(calls[[i]])))
      locations <- c(locations, sprintf("%s:%d", getSrcFilename(srcref), srcref[1]))
  
  # If we found any locations, redo the warning
  # with those locations prepended to the message
  
  if (length(locations)) {
    call <- if (!is.null(e$call)) paste("In", deparse(e$call)) else ""
    warning(sprintf("%s at %s: %s", call, paste(locations, collapse=","), conditionMessage(e)), call. = FALSE)
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
  }
}


withCallingHandlers(fun(x, y), 
                    warning = locatedWarnings)
#> Warning: In fun(x, y) at <text>:5: Potential problem
#> [1] 30
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you put this example in a file and source it with the default `keep.source = TRUE`, you'll get the filename and line for the warning line as well as the `withCallingHandlers()` line.  Not sure why `reprex` didn't give the second one.  If you just execute it by cut and paste to the console you won't get very useful line info, because every statement restarts the line count.