# Saving workspace (in a particular frame) for post-mortem debugging in R

Tags: r, debugging, r-markdown

While debug some R code, I'd like to save the workspace (i.e. all present objects) in some particular frame so that I can utilize those objects **outside of the the debugging browser**.  Following the example given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412582/getting-the-state-of-variables-after-an-error-occurs-in-r):

```
x <- 1:5
y <- x + rnorm(length(x),0,1)
f <- function(x,y) {
  y <- c(y,1)
  lm(y~x)
}
```

Setting `options(error = recover)` and running `f(x,y)` allows us to pick which frame to enter.  Here I'll pick `2` and check my workspace with `ls()` like so:

```
Browse[1]> ls()
 [1] "cl" "contrasts" "data" "formula" "m" "method" "mf" "model" "na.action" "offset" "qr"         
[12] "ret.x" "ret.y" "singular.ok" "subset" "weights" "x" "y"
```

I'd like to be able to save all of these objects to use them later.  Using `save.image()` in the browser, or inserting it into the relevant function, saves the environment `f(x,y)` was originally called from.  I can use `dump.frames()` and call `debugger()` on the resulting `dump.frames` classed object, but I still have to work interactively from within the debugging browser.  All I really want is an `.RData` file containing the 18 above listed objects.

The point of all this is to reproduce certain errors within an R Markdown document.  If anyone has an idea for that particular application it would be appreciated.

Comment: I would encourage you to ask about your R markdown errors, rather than ask how to implement a solution you've thought of. Someone might know the solution to your markdown errors that would make this question moot.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - in short, because I don't know how to get an `.Rmd` file to interact with the debugging browser.  When `recover()` asks me to "Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit" how would I write that into an `.Rmd` file?  The resulting `.html` shows the error and moves on to the next line of code.  See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/duncandonutz/9f0fcd0aeff8278c8fa0).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
save(list=ls(), file="mylocals.Rda")
```

The hurdle I had to  get over to realize this was the way forward was the name of that argument in `save`. Why did the authors use the argument name, "list", when it was a character vector (and not a list)? Same whine applies to the `rm` function argument names.

Comment: Why not just `save.image(file="mylocals.Rda")`?

Comment: @hadley: The `save.image` code says it does this: `save(list = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv, all.names = TRUE), ...)`

Comment: Sorry, I was tricked (again!) by the documentation, which says: "save.image() is just a short-cut for ‘save my current workspace’, i.e., save(list = ls(all = TRUE), file = ".RData")."

Comment: @DWin - I'd love a quick "why" in addition to the "how".

Comment: Color me puzzled. I thought you had provided the why and only needed the how.

Comment: Nevermind, it's all about the difference between `ls(envir = .GlobalEnv)` and `ls()` while inside of the browser, which I understand now.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to be so dense. I thought you already understood that `ls()` was only returning the local objects in the browsing environment and that those would be different than the objects resident in `.GlobalEnv`.